# I am trying to make a pattern (triangle in java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to make this pattern in java:

```
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

This is the code which I have written:

```
package practise;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternsUsingLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();       
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) { 
            for(int k=n;k>=1;k--) {

                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**please tell me the error**

Comment: Hey! It would be a nice thing to show the *current* output of your code.

Comment: Krish, what is the code doing now? Does it run at all, and if so what is the output? How do you want it to work (it looks like you want to enter a number of stars to start with).Perhaps you could edit the question to improve it so we can give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it also to fix this issue. One of the simplest fixes is to replace the inner loop with the following:

```
for (int k = (n - j) + 1; k >= 1; k--)
```

Since you want to print `n` number of `*`s in the first line, `n - 1` number of `*`s in the second line and so on, the value of `k` must be initialized to `n` when `j` is `1`, `n - 1` when `j` is `2` and so on.

Some of the other ways to do this requirement are as follows:

**A.**

```
for (int j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
    for (int k = j; k >= 1; k--) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**B.**

```
for (int j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

...and many more

Answer (score 1):

You don't decrease the finish condition in inner loop. This will works:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int row=0;row<n;row++) { 
        for (int column = 0; column < n-row; column++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very small mistake that you are doing , the first loop is correct but in the inner loop you are printing n stars again (from n to 1). 
You need to print (n - i + 1) stars for every loop.

Use this change :

```
...
...
int n = sc.nextInt();       
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) { 
            for(int k=n-j+1;k>=1;k--) {

                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
...
...
```

//... means same code //

Comment: Where is `i` defined  ? It is not recommended to post untested code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't tried debugging your code.
To debug your code try printing out the variables that you are using at the beginning of each line to see if they are what you expect. You have (hopefully) thought about the code, and what you *think* each variable will be on each line, so you've missed something, you have a bug.

For example try this:

```
package practise;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternsUsingLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();       
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) { 
            System.out.print("j: " + j + " n: " + n);
            for(int k=n;k>=1;k--) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run that you get

```
j: 1 n: 5* * * * * 
j: 2 n: 5* * * * * 
j: 3 n: 5* * * * * 
j: 4 n: 5* * * * * 
j: 5 n: 5* * * * *
```

Which shows what a couple of the other answers are pointing out, that n doesn't change so the output is always 5 stars.

Now you can figure out the answer. (Hint: start j from 0 and use k=n-j)